# How to delete the tableview cell without pressing delete button?

Tags: ios

```
 - (NSArray *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editActionsForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView1 cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    UITableViewRowAction *flagAction = [UITableViewRowAction rowActionWithStyle:UITableViewRowActionStyleDefault title:@"Delete" handler:^(UITableViewRowAction *action, NSIndexPath *indexPath) {

    [tableData removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"indexpath %ld",indexPath.row);
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}];
    return @[ flagAction];
}
```

Comment: I want to remove the cell from tableview without pressing delete button in the cell. Is there any possibility. i want to delete the list by only swiping without pressing delete button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can add swipe gesture to table and delete row as shown following.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *gestureDeleteRow = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self          action:@selector(cellSwipe:)];
    gestureDeleteRow.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
    [tableView addGestureRecognizer:gestureDeleteRow];
}

//Swipe Handler Method
-(void)cellSwipe:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    CGPoint location = [gesture locationInView:tableView];
    NSIndexPath *swipedIndexPath = [tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:location];
    //Delete Row…
    [ARRAY removeObjectAtIndex: swipedIndexPath.row];
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:swipedIndexPath, nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
}
```

Comment: ya its working perfectly. thank you. but with a minor change in code. Instead of showExtrasSwipe.direction use gestureDeleteRow.direction. Thats it. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Check this Code with **swipe table cell** with animation
[Github Code](https://github.com/alikaragoz/MCSwipeTableViewCell)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.